# Wrong IIS outbound rewrite being applied

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I've had a lot of issues with reverse proxy rewrites.

We have one that was working.  We have our live website, and it passes the request off to our business app site for processing, with the reverse proxy showing the live website url.

So.... https://mywebsite.com/application/startApp
goes to http://businessApp.com/application/startApp

This works just fine.

So, on my "mywebsite.com, I have the "application" folder enabled as a web application. Within that directory, I have this rewrite reverse proxy setup:

```
Inbound Rule, Pattern: (.*)
Action Type - Rewrite
Rewrite URL: http://businessApp.com/application/{R:1}

Outbound Rule, Matching Scope: Response;   Match the content within: A, Form, Img
Pattern: ^http(s)?://businessApp.com/(.*)
Action Type - Rewrite
Rewrite URL: http:{R:1}://mywebsite.com/{R:2}
```

since both ends of this have the same "application" directory, it works fine.

**NEW SCENARIO**

We are building a test environment on the back end, but for testing reasons, we need the web app to run on our regular web server - no separate server, just a different URL directory. We created a second shell directory, called "application_test" as the reverse proxy pass through and converted it to a web application.  We want this traffic to go to our backed development server businessAppDev.com.

So..... when traffic comes from our mywebsite.com/application_test it has to be routed to businessAppDev.com/application (note the difference in folder name)

Here's how I set up the reverse proxy rule that is NOT working -

```
Inbound Rule, Pattern: (.*)
Action Type - Rewrite
Rewrite URL: http://businessAppDev.com/application/{R:1}

Outbound Rule, Matching Scope: Response;   Match the content within: A, Form, Img
Pattern: ^http(s)?://businessAppDev.com/application/(.*)
Action Type - Rewrite
Rewrite URL: http:{R:1}://mywebsite.com/application_test/{R:2}
```

It looks like the original traffic from the application_test to the dev server application folder is working correctly, but the return (outbound) traffic is directing to the "application" folder, which then directs subsequent interaction to the wrong server, which fails because the initial authentications weren't done there.

Why is it forcing that directory?  Also, I said to log the rewrite urls. Should I be seeing specific log entries of the rewrite being invoked, or just that addresses are included in other log entries?

I tried to put this precondition on the "application" outbound rule to stop it from sending the wrong traffic to that folder (should this be a condition instead of a precondition) -

```
{HTTP_HOST} Matches the pattern ^businessApp.com
```

and this precondition on the "application_test" outbound rule

```
{HTTP_HOST} Matches the pattern ^businessAppDev.com
```

None of that made any difference, at all.

Windows Server 2016
IIS 10

ADDENDUM:

I went to the following site, which was enlightening -

[The Very Common Mistakes When Using IIS URL Rewrite Module](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59)

I changed the outbound rules to operate at the domain root level, removed that part from the match conditions, and made the server source a condition for the rules, and no change was seen.  I've concluded that I'm probably not catching and rewriting that traffic at all, and it's just directly routing to the matching directory.

Comment: When some rules do not work, read FRT trace to learn more, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr

Comment: @LexLi - Ahhhh, I see..... expand the codes that define "failed request" to get them logged.  Sounds good. Thanks!

Comment: @LexLi - Looks like that only works for inbound, where my issue is strictly outbound.

Comment: Winds up, we do have the capability to run an entire identical test environment on another web server, contrary to what we were originally told, so the necessity of this is no more, but I'd like to know if there is an answer, nonetheless.